# How to deploy a Tensorflow app

Tags: java, python, tensorflow, gcloud, google-cloud-ml

I finished my first Tensorflow application, it works. Now, how do I let others use it? The Google ML documentation never mentions this ... it only explains how to get predictions using gloud, as in:

```
gcloud ml-engine predict --model $MODEL_NAME --version v1 --json-instances test.json
```

But how can this be done from within someone else's Java or Go program? To make matters worse, my input will consist of a JSON statement with feature - value pairs, e.g.,

```
{"x67":5,"category":"black", ....}
```

where "black" needs to be one-hot coded first.

Somehow, I would like to make the translation part of the saved Tensorflow model ...

Comment: [here](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/deploying-models)

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer was sufficient to point me in the right direction. Also, the fFeatures objects have all the functionality I needed for recoding the various input types.

Answer (score 0):

The steps between training a model and using it for predictions on the cloud are creating a model resource in Cloud ML Engine and then creating a model version from your saved model. Basically, you need to [deploy](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/deploying-models) your [SavedModel](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model) to Cloud ML Engine. Probably the most straightforward way to go about this is by using the following gcloud commands:

```
$ gcloud ml-engine models create $MODEL
$ gcloud ml-engine versions create $VERSION --model=$MODEL --origin $DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE
```

Check [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ml-engine/models/create) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ml-engine/versions/create) for more details on these two. You should also read through [this](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/prediction-overview) enlightening article on the basics of prediction on the Cloud ML Engine.